# Starting different applications

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm new to C#, but i'm making a little application.

You can add applications (with OpenFileDialog).
It links the added application to a button (extracts file icon and exe name).
Then when you click the button it starts the application you added.

You can add up to 5 applications (5 buttons), this all works. But if you add more then 1 application it only opens the last added application.

So if i add lets say Word / Excel / Outlook, it will only open Outlook on all the buttons.

**My question is:**

How can i make it so it remembers what application to open when the button is clicked.

**Appliction screenshot so you can have a visual:**

http://s24.postimg.org/467l561dh/Untitled.png

**Code**

```
public partial class QuickStarter : Form
{
    public QuickStarter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Icon ico = null;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void application1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
            button1.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button1.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void application2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
            button2.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button2.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void application3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
            button3.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button3.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void application4ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
            button4.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button4.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
            button4.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void application5ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
            button5.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button5.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
            button5.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @ofd.FileName;
        Process.Start(start);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @ofd.FileName;
        Process.Start(start);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @ofd.FileName;
        Process.Start(start);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @ofd.FileName;
        Process.Start(start);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @ofd.FileName;
        Process.Start(start);
    }

    private void resetApplicationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            button1.Text = "Application";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Image = null;
            button2.Text = "Application";
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button2.Image = null;
            button3.Text = "Application";
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button3.Image = null;
            button4.Text = "Application";
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button4.Image = null;
            button5.Text = "Application";
            button5.Enabled = false;
            button5.Image = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: saving each application path somewhere?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually store the filename data somewhere to do what you want to do. Currently, you are reusing the `OpenFileDialog` instance for every application chosen so only the information for the last file selected will be saved.

You can add a private field to store this information. If you are only going to have 5 buttons a simple array will work.

```
public partial class QuickStarter : Form
{
    public QuickStarter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Icon ico = null;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    // Added
    string[] fileNames = new string[5];
```

Now in your handler to add a button, you would add the line

```
private void application1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
    ofd.Title = "Add application";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName);
        button1.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
        button1.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
        button1.Enabled = true;

        // Added Line
        fileNames[0] = ofd.FileName;
    }
}
```

Now in your on click button handler, instead of pulling the name from the `OpenFileDialog` you pull it from the array.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = fileNames[0];
    Process.Start(start);
}
```

Now you will be opening the correct application. Just be sure to change the index of the array to the correct number for each handler.

In regards to the overall design though, you have a lot of repeated code. You can probably reduce all of this code to two event handlers, storing data based on who the `object sender` is. This would also allow you to add or remove buttons later without having to add or remove their associated event handlers. This would also add some extra logic to storing the information. At that point a `List<string>` or perhaps a `Dictionary<string, string>` would be more useful than a basic array.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the OpenFileDialogPath to run the program. This means that your buttons only work for the last added Program

What you want to do is, remember the .exe-Path for each Button like this:

```
Dictionary<Button,string> _exePaths = new Dictionary<Button,string>();

private void application1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _userSelectExe(button1);
}

private void application2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _userSelectExe(button2);
}
and so on
```

The _userSelectExe Method :

```
private void _userSelectExe(Button button)
{      
    using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.Filter = "EXE|*.exe";
        ofd.Title = "Add application";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            exePaths[button] = ofd.FileName;
            button.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);
            button.Image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ofd.FileName).ToBitmap();
            button.Enabled = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then start each one like this:

```
// Assign this eventhandler to every button
private void _allButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _startButton((Button) sender);
}


private void _startButton(Button button)
{
    string path;
    if(_exePaths.TryGetValue(button, out path)) 
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = path;
        Process.Start(start);
    } else MessageBox.Show("No Exe for this button defined!");
}
```